# Understanding the terminal and shell interaction

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, cygwin, console

For a long while my understanding about a **terminal** in unix-like systems has been that it launches the shell process and provides a user interface to it by communicating with it over it's *stdin*, *stdout* & *stderr*.

However recently while looking into a problem with launching a windows console application via a cygwin terminal, I realize it may not be as simple as that.

At http://cygwin.com/1.5/cygwin-ug-net/using-effectively.html I see,

> *Another issue is receiving output from or giving input to
>   console-based Windows programs. Unfortunately, interacting with
>   Windows console applications is not a simple matter of using a
>   translation utility. Windows console applications are designed to run
>   under command.com or cmd.exe, and some do not deal gracefully with
>   other situations. Cygwin can receive console input only if it is also
>   running in a console (DOS box) since Windows does not provide any way
>   to attach to the backend of the console device. Another traditional
>   Unix input/output method, ptys (pseudo-terminals), is supported by
>   Cygwin but not entirely by Windows. The basic problem is that a Cygwin
>   pty is a pipe and some Windows applications do not like having their
>   input or output redirected to pipes.*

I wrote a little C program which I compiled under windows using VC++'s *cl.exe* -

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    #define BUFFER_LEN 1024
    char buffer[BUFFER_LEN];

    printf("echo server started\n"); 
    while (fgets(buffer, BUFFER_LEN, stdin) != NULL) {
        printf("%s", buffer);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I run the Cygwin terminal (*mintty.exe*) and launch this program, I cannot interact with it -

```
[puneet@freestyle ~]$ /cygdrive/c/echo1.exe
Hello
```

^-- no response

But when I put it in a pipe, it works -

```
[puneet@freestyle ~]$ echo  -e "1\n2\n3" | /cygdrive/c/echo1.exe | while read line; do echo $line; done
1
2
3
[puneet@freestyle ~]$
```

Basically it fails to interact with the *mintty.exe* terminal. However when running *bash.exe* directly from a windows console, it can be correctly interacted with -

```
[puneet@freestyle ~]$ /cygdrive/c/echo1.exe
Hello
Hello
^Z
[puneet@freestyle ~]$
```

I then thought if I *ssh*'d into my machine and ran this program as a command, it would work as then the terminal wouldn't directly interact with it, but the SSH server will. However that doesn't work too -

```
[puneet@freestyle ~]$ ssh freestyle /cygdrive/c/echo1.exe
Hello
```

^-- no response

But putting this in a pipe again works ! -

```
[puneet@freestyle ~]$ echo  -e "1\n2\n3" | ssh freestyle /cygdrive/c/echo1.exe | while read line; do echo $line; done
1
2
3
[puneet@freestyle ~]$
```

Could someone explain the theory behind all these observations?

Is the interaction between the terminal and the shell more than just using the shell's *stdin*, *stdout* and *stderr*?

How is the windows console different? Why do the windows console programs seem to work fine when in a pipe with the cygwin programs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add `fflush(stdout)` to your `while` loop (after `printf`), then your program will work as you expect, even inside mintty.  You should also be able to call `setbuf(stdout, NULL)` as the first operation you do on stdout, and have that work.

You can also run c:\cygwin\bin\bash inside your windows console window and your original program will work as you except.  I haven't tried it but you should also be able to run bash inside a conemu or console2 window and have your original program work as you expect.

That is to say: this is about mintty.

Here's (part of) what's going on:

The windows console is very special.  Windows has a service called  Client/Server Runtime Subsystem.  When you start a cmd prompt on Windows, what you are actually doing is connecting to the Client/Server Runtime Subsystem, and *it* is creating the window for you.

Mintty, on the other hand is a "regular" window (that happens to be running a terminal emulator).

Microsoft's C library i/o routines actually test whether they are running under a window created by the Client/Server Runtime Subsystem and change their behavior if they are.  One change they make is to turn off full buffering for stdout.

When you run under mintty the Window's gets/puts routines think they are not running in a command prompt, so they are doing full buffering.

Here's one more trick: under `bash` running under `mintty` you can run `cat | echo1.exe`.  Then type some stuff, and when you hit `^D` all of that buffered stdout output will show up all at once.

The reason that the `cat | echo1.exe` trick works is that `cat` is a cygwin program.  Cygwin is really, at heart, a posix emulation library.  So the `stdin` of `cat` is emulated by the Cygwin library, and the Cygwin library treats `^D` differently than a "real" Windows stdin would.

But if you just run `echo1.exe` under `bash` under `mintty` then your keystrokes are going into a non-emulated file stream (i.e., your stdin is a real Windows stdin, not one emulated by the Cygwin library), so `^D` does not send eof.  Instead `^Z` would send eof, but `^Z` means something special to bash, so it doesn't get sent. Rather you need to hit `^C` which terminates `echo1.exe` immediately (and doesn't flush the buffers, which is correct.)

Comment: thanks for your answer! Output buffering explains a lot! Could you elaborate a little more on why the `^D` doesn't reach `echo1.exe` and what is a _non-emulated_ file stream?

Comment: I just made some edits (last 2 paragraphs).  Does that explain the emulation/non-emulation better?

Comment: thanks, that makes it more clear! I'm still curious about how bash captures the ^Z? Isn't the DOS program running in foreground?

Comment: I'm getting way out of my depth here. My guess is that mintty is capturing the ^Z and (somehow) passing it to bash instead of the foreground program.  I think this is somehow part of the way that mintty and cygwin are emulating the notion of a Unix tty.  If you run bash under a windows console the ^Z _does_ go to the foreground program.